# помогите улучшить архитектуру кода: изменить модель, отделить логику от UI, разбить на файлы (c# + winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, инспекция-кода, архитектура

Привет

Я сделал тестовое задание, хотел бы попросить поревьюить код, что бы его улучшить.

Нужно: 
    - улучшить архитектуру: изменить модель данных, правильно разбить код на файлы
    - полностью развязать модель и UI
    - внедрить другие паттерны проектирования
    - внедрить MVC (если нужно)

Задание 3. Модель автоматического аппарата быстрого питания.
Необходимо выполнить реализацию задачи с максимальным использованием преимуществ объектно-ориентированного подхода и, по возможности, реализовать подходящие архитектурные шаблоны проектирования приложений.
В качестве результата нужно предоставить UML-диаграмму классов предметной области или приложение реализующее работу вышеупомянутого аппарата или и то и другое.
Создать объектную модель аппарата по быстрому приготовлению напитков и еды со следующими допущениями:

1. Латте – это эспрессо + молоко
2. Капучино – эспрессо + молоко + молочная пенка
3. Молоко можно добавлять к следующим напиткам: эспрессо, латте, чай черный, чай зеленый
4. Сахар можно добавлять ко всем напиткам. Количество порций сахара указывается пользователем (от 0 до 5).
5. Ветчину, сыр можно добавлять к хлебу и булочке (получается бутерброд)
6. Комплекс – это набор из напитка и еды по фиксированной цене. При этом можно выбрать любой элемент из категории «Напиток» + один элемент из «Добавки к напиткам», аналогично с едой: 1 элемент из категории «Еда» + 1 элемент из категории «Добавки к еде».
   Задание.
7. Аппарат должен считать стоимость выбранного заказа и выводить в окно со стоимостью.
8. После нажатия на кнопку выдать, в диалоговом окне выводить строку с составом заказа, например, Капучино (Эспрессо+Молоко+Сахар)
   Бутерброд (Хлеб+Ветчина).
   В случае реализации приложения учитывать следующее ограничение:
   Язык реализации: C#
   Уровень представления: Windows Forms или Web-приложение

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using static WindowsFormsApp1.CoffeeMachine;


   namespace WindowsFormsApp1
   {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
           private CoffeeMachine coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine();
           public Form1()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               Init();
           }

           private void Init()
           {
               radioButtonEspresso.Text = new Espresso().Name + new Espresso().GetCost() + " руб";
               radioButtonLatte.Text = "Латте - " + coffeeMachine.GetLatte().GetCost() + " руб";
               radioButtonCapuchino.Text = "Капуччино - " + coffeeMachine.GetCapuchino().GetCost() + " руб";
               radioButtonBlackTea.Text = new BlackTea().Name + new BlackTea().GetCost() + " руб";
               radioButtonGreenTea.Text = new GreenTea().Name + new GreenTea().GetCost() + " руб";
               radioButtonWater.Text = new Water().Name + new Water().GetCost() + " руб";

               radioButtonBread.Text = new Bread().Name + new Bread().GetCost() + " руб";
               radioButtonRoll.Text = new Roll().Name + new Roll().GetCost() + " руб";
               radioButtonChips.Text = new Chips().Name + new Chips().GetCost() + " руб";
               radioButtonCookie.Text = new Cookie().Name + new Cookie().GetCost() + " руб";

               Meals blankObject = new Espresso();
               checkBoxMilk.Text = new Milk(blankObject).Name + new Milk(blankObject).Cost;
               checkBoxSugar.Text = new Sugar(blankObject).Name + new Sugar(blankObject).Cost;
               checkBoxSyrop.Text = new Syrop(blankObject).Name + new Syrop(blankObject).Cost;
               checkBoxHam.Text = new Ham(blankObject).Name + new Ham(blankObject).Cost;
               checkBoxCheese.Text = new Cheese(blankObject).Name + new Cheese(blankObject).Cost;
               checkBoxJam.Text = new Jam(blankObject).Name + new Jam(blankObject).Cost;

               checkBoxComplex.Text = "Комплекс (1 напиток с любой добавкой + 1 еда с любой добавкой на выбор)";
               labelComplexCost.Text = "90 руб";

               radioButtonBread.Checked = true;
           }

           private void ShowCost(int cost)
           {
               textBoxCost.Text = cost.ToString();
           }

           private void RecountMealsCost()
           {
               Dictionary<Meals, bool> beverageChoice = new Dictionary<Meals, bool>()
               {
                   {new Espresso(), radioButtonEspresso.Checked},
                   {coffeeMachine.GetLatte(), radioButtonLatte.Checked},
                   {coffeeMachine.GetCapuchino(), radioButtonCapuchino.Checked },
                   {new BlackTea(), radioButtonBlackTea.Checked},
                   {new GreenTea(), radioButtonGreenTea.Checked},
                   {new Water(), radioButtonWater.Checked } 
               };
               RecountBeverageCost(beverageChoice.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == true).Key);

               Dictionary<Meals, bool> foodChoice = new Dictionary<Meals, bool>()
               {
                   { new Bread(), radioButtonBread.Checked},
                   { new Roll(), radioButtonRoll.Checked},
                   { new Chips(), radioButtonChips.Checked},
                   { new Cookie(), radioButtonCookie.Checked}
               };
               RecountFoodCost(foodChoice.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == true).Key);

               int totalCost = coffeeMachine.BeverageCost + coffeeMachine.FoodCost;
               ShowCost(totalCost);
               buttonGiveOrder.Enabled = coffeeMachine.IsComplexOrderEnabled(checkBoxComplex.Checked, totalCost);
           }

           private void RecountBeverageCost(Meals meal)
           {
               if (meal.GetType().Name != "Milk")
               {
                   meal =  coffeeMachine.AddAdditionIfChecked(checkBoxMilk.Checked, meal, new Milk(meal));
                   checkBoxMilk.Enabled = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   checkBoxMilk.Enabled = false;
               }

               for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDownSugarPieces.Value; i++)
               {
                   meal = coffeeMachine.AddAdditionIfChecked(checkBoxSugar.Checked, meal, new Sugar(meal));
               }
               meal = coffeeMachine.AddAdditionIfChecked(checkBoxSyrop.Checked, meal, new Syrop(meal));
               coffeeMachine.BeverageCost = meal.GetCost();
           }

           private void RecountFoodCost(Meals meal)
           {
               if (meal.GetType().Name == "Bread" || meal.GetType().Name == "Roll")
               {
                   meal = coffeeMachine.AddAdditionIfChecked(checkBoxHam.Checked, meal, new Ham(meal));
                   meal = coffeeMachine.AddAdditionIfChecked(checkBoxCheese.Checked, meal, new Cheese(meal));
                   checkBoxHam.Enabled = true;
                   checkBoxCheese.Enabled = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   checkBoxHam.Enabled = false;
                   checkBoxCheese.Enabled = false;
               }

               meal = coffeeMachine.AddAdditionIfChecked(checkBoxJam.Checked, meal, new Jam(meal));
               coffeeMachine.FoodCost = meal.GetCost();
           }

           private void radioButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               RecountMealsCost();
           }

           private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               RecountMealsCost();
           }

           private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               RecountMealsCost();
           }

           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               string caption = new Order().GetInfo(groupBox1, groupBox2, groupBox3, groupBox4).Caption;
               string message = new Order().GetInfo(groupBox1, groupBox2, groupBox3, groupBox4).Message;
               MessageBox.Show(caption, message, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
           }
       }
   }







   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace WindowsFormsApp1
   {
       public class CoffeeMachine
       {
           public int BeverageCost { get; set; }
           public int FoodCost { get; set; }
           private int complexCost = 90;

           public abstract class Meals
           {
               public Meals(string name)
               {
                   this.Name = name;
               }
               public string Name { get; protected set; }
               public abstract int GetCost();
           }

           public class Espresso : Meals
           {
               public Espresso() : base("Эспрессо - ")
               { }

               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return 60;
               }
           }

           public class BlackTea : Meals
           {
               public BlackTea() : base("Чёрный чай - ")
               { }
               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return 25;
               }
           }

           public class GreenTea : Meals
           {
               public GreenTea() : base("Зелёный чай - ")
               { }
               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return 25;
               }
           }

           public class Water : Meals
           {
               public Water() : base("Вода - ")
               { }
               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return 20;
               }
           }

           public abstract class MealsDecorator : Meals
           {
               protected Meals meals;
               protected int cost;
               protected string name;
               public MealsDecorator(string name, Meals meals) : base(name)
               {
                   this.meals = meals;
               }
           }

           public class Milk : MealsDecorator
           {
               public Milk(Meals meals)
                   : base(meals.Name, meals)
               { }

               public string Name { get; set; } = "Молоко - ";
               public int Cost { get; set; } = 10;

               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return meals.GetCost() + Cost;
               }
           }

           public class MilkFroth : MealsDecorator
           {
               public MilkFroth(Meals meals)
                   : base(meals.Name + "Молочная пенка - ", meals)
               { }

               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   this.cost = 10;
                   return meals.GetCost() + this.cost;
               }
           }

           public class Syrop : MealsDecorator
           {
               public Syrop(Meals meals)
                   : base(meals.Name, meals)
               { }

               public string Name { get; set; } = "Сироп - ";
               public int Cost { get; set; } = 5;

               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return meals.GetCost() + Cost;
               }
           }

           public class Sugar : MealsDecorator
           {
               public Sugar(Meals meals)
                   : base(meals.Name, meals)
               { }

               public string Name { get; set; } = "Сахар - ";
               public int Cost { get; set; } = 5;

               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return meals.GetCost() + Cost;
               }
           }

           public class Ham : MealsDecorator
           {
               public Ham(Meals meals)
                   : base(meals.Name, meals)
               { }

               public string Name { get; set; } = "Ветчина - ";
               public int Cost { get; set; } = 15;

               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return meals.GetCost() + Cost;
               }
           }

           public class Cheese : MealsDecorator
           {
               public Cheese(Meals meals)
                   : base(meals.Name, meals)
               { }

               public string Name { get; set; } = "Сыр - ";
               public int Cost { get; set; } = 10;

               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return meals.GetCost() + Cost;
               }
           }

           public class Jam : MealsDecorator
           {
               public Jam(Meals meals)
                   : base(meals.Name, meals)
               { }

               public string Name { get; set; } = "Джем - ";
               public int Cost { get; set; } = 7;

               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return meals.GetCost() + Cost;
               }
           }

           public Meals GetLatte()
           {
               return new Milk(new Espresso());
           }

           public Meals GetCapuchino()
           {
               return new MilkFroth(new Milk(new Espresso()));
           }

           public class Bread : Meals
           {
               public Bread() : base("Хлеб - ")
               { }
               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return 10;
               }
           }

           public class Roll : Meals
           {
               public Roll() : base("Булочка - ")
               { }
               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return 15;
               }
           }

           public class Chips : Meals
           {
               public Chips() : base("Чипсы - ")
               { }
               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return 34;
               }
           }

           public class Cookie : Meals
           {
               public Cookie() : base("Печенье - ")
               { }
               public override int GetCost()
               {
                   return 29;
               }
           }

           public Meals AddAdditionIfChecked(bool isControlChecked, Meals meal, MealsDecorator decorator)
           {
               if (isControlChecked)
               {
                   meal = decorator;
               }
               return meal;
           }

           public bool IsComplexOrderEnabled(bool controlStateToEnable, int cost)
           {
               if (controlStateToEnable == true && cost > complexCost)
                   return false;

               return true;
           }
       }
   }


   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace WindowsFormsApp1
   {
       class Order
       {
           public string BeverageName { get; set; }
           public string[] BeverageAdditionsNames { get; set; }
           public string FoodName { get; set; }
           public string[] FoodAdditionsNames { get; set; }
           public Order(string beverageName, 
                        string[] beverageAdditionsNames,
                        string foodName,
                        string[] foodAdditionsNames)
           {
               BeverageName = beverageName;
               FoodName = foodName;
               BeverageAdditionsNames = beverageAdditionsNames;
               FoodAdditionsNames = foodAdditionsNames;
           }

           public string Message { get; set; }
           public string Caption { get; set; }
           public Order(string message, string caption) {
               Message = message;
               Caption = caption;
           }

           public Order() { }

           public Order Get<T1, T2, T3>(T3 beverages, T3 beverageAdditions,
                                        T3 foods,     T3 foodAdditions)        where T1: RadioButton
                                                                               where T2: CheckBox
                                                                               where T3: GroupBox
           {
               Func<Control, string> GetName = x => { return x.Text.Split(new string[] {" -"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]; };
               Func<T1, bool> RadiobuttonChecked = x => { return x.Checked == true; };
               Func<T2, bool> CheckboxChecked = x => { return x.Checked == true; };
               Func<T2, bool> CheckboxEnabled = x => { return x.Enabled == true; };

               var beverage = GetControls<T1>(beverages).Where(RadiobuttonChecked).Select(GetName).SingleOrDefault();

               var beverageAddition = GetControls<T2>(beverageAdditions).Where(CheckboxChecked).Select(GetName).ToArray();

               var food = GetControls<T1>(foods).Where(RadiobuttonChecked).Select(GetName).SingleOrDefault();

               var foodAddition = GetControls<T2>(foodAdditions).Where(CheckboxChecked).Where(CheckboxEnabled).Select(GetName).ToArray();

               return new Order(beverage, beverageAddition, food, foodAddition);
           }

           private IEnumerable<T> GetControls<T>(GroupBox source)
           {
               return source.Controls.OfType<T>();
           }

           public Order GetInfo<T>(T beverages, T beverageAdditions, T foods, T foodAdditions) where T: GroupBox
           {
               Order order = Get<RadioButton, CheckBox, GroupBox>(beverages, beverageAdditions, foods, foodAdditions);
               string beverageDelimiter = ", ";
               string foodDelimiter = beverageDelimiter;
               string additionsDelimeter = beverageDelimiter;

               var chosenBeverageAdditions = string.Join(beverageDelimiter, order.BeverageAdditionsNames);
               var chosenFoodAdditions = string.Join(foodDelimiter, order.FoodAdditionsNames);

               if (chosenBeverageAdditions == string.Empty)
                   beverageDelimiter = null;
               if (chosenFoodAdditions == string.Empty)
                   foodDelimiter = null;

               string caption = "Заказ";
               string message = "Напиток: " + order.BeverageName + beverageDelimiter + chosenBeverageAdditions + "\n" +
                                "Еда: " + order.FoodName + foodDelimiter + chosenFoodAdditions;
               return new Order(caption, message);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. Все вопросы по улучшению кодов будут озаглавлены, как у Вас. Вы сами смогли бы найти улучшение конкретного кода в сотнях одинаковых тем? Как после Вас посетители смогут ориентироваться? Название должно отражать смысл конкретной задачи.=== 2. Вы думаете, кому-то интресно пересматривать эту "простыню" листинга? Конкретизируйте.

Comment: Как мне избавиться от зависимостей (new Espresso() и т.д.) в классе Form1, метод init. ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы умеет кодировать (ну вот в коде я вижу дженерики например), но архитектуры в приложении я не вижу.

Во-первых, паттерн MVC говорит о том, что нужно разделять логику (доменную модель) от UI. Имея написанный слой доменной логики вы можете легко заменить проект с WebForms на скажем Asp.Net или что-то другое -- а домен при этом не поменяется.

А посмотрите на ваш класс Order. Это доменная логика, в ней нельзя ничего знать о UI, но в ваш класс Order просочилось знание о конкретной реализации UI: вы пишете button.Checked

Возьмите студию, создайте проект Domain и попробуйте написать предметную область, не подключая неймспейсы WinForm. Удалось - отлично, добавляйте в solution новый проект WinFormsUI, создавайте в нём ссылку на Domain и дописывайте недостающую конкретику в UI.

Второй момент связан с передачей зависимостей. Вы знаете о том, что такое зависимость, как её передать на конструктор и почему внутри метода не должно быть слова new (у вас 56 раз встретилось в проекте)? Если знаете, то почему не сделали?

Далее. О предметной области. Я могу подойти к аппарату и заказать что-то, не являющееся комплексным обедом? Я могу взять две чашки чая и один бутерброд, а потом нажать кнопку "рассчитать стоимость"? Или взять одну чашку чая нажать "рассчитать стоимость"?

Мне мнится, что в предметной области должен быть некоторый класс Order, который имеет метод AddToOrder и метод IsOrderComplex, который бы проверял текущий набор того, чего уже понадобавляли.

Я думаю, что класс "Еда", от которого вы наследуете нужно заменить на Product, потому что именно продукт имеет не только Title, но и Price.

И, мало ли, нужно будет расширить архитектуру на продажу непродовольственных товаров, например, продавать контейнер для еды, салфетки или что-то ещё.

Непонятно, зачем описывать кучу классов отнаследованных от Еды, когда можно было создать класс Продукт с конструктором принимающим Title и Price в качестве обязательных полей. Вы представляете реальное приложение, в котором программист добавляет в коде новый класс? Или кто-то в базе данных создаёт строчку, а вы можете создать массив продуктов, раз у вас базу не требуют или читать из конфиг-файла. Конфиг же более гибко, чем перекомпилировать приложение после добавления нового класса, верно?

Также мнится мне, что можно было бы продемонстрировать паттерн фабрика, который бы умел создавать Order из накликанного "нам два кофе чай и два бутерброда" или создавать сразу комплексный ордер. У вас же такой жесткий хардкод, что приложение получается строго по ТЗ "автомат для накликивания комплексных обедов", но архитектура не предусматривает расширяемости. Если надо взять два кофе и один бутерброд – мы будем переписывать приложение, а пока будем рекомендовать костыль "сделайте сначала один заказ, а потом другой"?

И ещё момент. У вас можно добавлять к заказу напиток и для некоторых напитков возможна добавка молоко. Вот как вы архитектурно реализуете эту бизнес-логику? Сейчас её нигде нет, тупо везде хардкод.

Гипотетически. Можно было бы сделать класс "напиток" с абстрактным "в_напиток_можно_добавлять_дополнительное_молоко". Создавая потомков переопределять: кому-то false, кому-то true. А фабрика, которая конструирует напитки будет работать с этим свойством и не даст возможность добавить допмолоко туда, куда нельзя добавить.
Вариантов куча: можно в продукт запилить продукт_тайп, например. Была бы другая архитектура.

Ради интереса сходите в макдональдс. Там не WinForms, а наверное веб-сайт, но есть интерфейс, в котором прекрасно виден UI - жмякнули "кола", нажали "кастом", выбрали "без льда <s>и с молоком</s>". И стоимость заказа считается на лету. Мне кажется, что у вас глядя на этот интерфейс появятся мысли что поменять в доменной модели и как можно построить UI на winforms.

Comment: Еще нужно добавить, что это Автомат, а не бездонная бочка, а значит в автомате имеется ограниченние на возможное число продуктов, которые имеют свойство заканчиваться с различной скоростью в зависимости от популярности того или иного продукта.

Comment: @Bulson Кстати и на объём лотка выдачи (видел такие лотки, в которые падают предметы) тогда.